# When is a locally metrizable space actually metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is metrizable when there is a metric that induces the topology.

A topological space is locally metrizable when every point has some neighbourhood that is metrizable.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_metrizable_space) Smirnov showed that a space is locally metrizable when iff it is Hausdorff and paracompact.

But the page for [paracompactness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact) says that a space is metrizable when it is locally metrisable, hausdorff and paracompact.

This doesn't seem right if the result by Smirnov is correct.

How does one characterise when a locally metrisable space is actually metrisable?

Comment: "Smirnov proved that a locally metrizable space is metrizable if and only if it is Hausdorff and paracompact. In particular, a manifold is metrizable if and only if it is paracompact." Looks like a misreading.

Comment: @Fischer: well, that makes sense since manifolds are generally taken to be hausdorff; however the paracompactness page says that "A topological space is metrizable if and only if it is a paracompact and locally metrizable Hausdorff space." - this is what I was asking about. Have I misread this?

Comment: You misread the sentence on the metrization theorem page, I pasted it here from wikipedia, Smirnov proved that a _locally metrizable space_ **is metrizable** if and only if ... .

Comment: ah, ok. thanks.